# Property Scope Issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to reference the `discount_code` property from within the object, but I keep getting the following error. How can I access `discount_code`?

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="txt_discount_code" value="12345" />
```

JS:

```
var cart = {
    transaction: {},
    discount_code: $('input[name=txt_discount_code]'),

    get_cart_items_params: {
        page: 'checkout',
        s_method: 'get-cart-items',
        txt_discount_code: this.discount_code.val()
        // txt_discount_code: cart.discount_code.val()
    }
};
```

Comment: It seems to me that `$('input[name=txt_discount_code]')` isn't working. Maybe you should debug from there.

Comment: If I try prefixing the code with `alert($('input[name=txt_discount_code]').val());`, it gives me the proper result, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work in the preceding context.

Comment: just replace your `this.discount_code.val()` with the selector.

Comment: or define it as a variable outside the scope of `cart` and reference it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like `ShankarSangoli` said, you can't access the object before it's defined.

You have to break up the declaration of `cart` into 2 parts:

```
var cart = {
    transaction: {},
    discount_code: $('input[name=txt_discount_code]')
};

cart.get_cart_items_params = {
    page: 'checkout',
    s_method: 'get-cart-items',
    txt_discount_code: cart.discount_code.val()
};
```

Or just put `discount_code` into a variable:

```
var $discount_code = $('input[name=txt_discount_code]');
var cart = {
    transaction: {},
    discount_code: $discount_code
    get_cart_items_params = {
        page: 'checkout',
        s_method: 'get-cart-items',
        txt_discount_code: $discount_code.val()
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the object before it is defined completely. It will never work.

Answer (score 1):

I initially believed that your issue lied on your jQuery selector but after I replaced the jQuery selector for a static value and try referencing it still didn't work. I came to the conclusion that you cannot reference the discount_code until you finalize the creation of the object:

Check out the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gLrFa/)

```
var cart = {
    transaction: {},

    get_cart_items_params: {
        page: 'checkout',
        s_method: 'get-cart-items',
        txt_discount_code: function(){
         return $('input[name="txt_discount_code"]').val();
        }
    }
};

cart.get_cart_items_params.txt_discount_code();
```